# How to handle image Caching in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on gallery related web application in react.I am trying to implement image cache in my application.I used local storage to store base64 string against image url.But the local storage limit is 5mb, Whenever i reach limit i am deleting images using LRU cache mechanism.I wanted to know is there any better approach.

```
code:

window.localstorage.setItem(url,base64 image string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you make life more complicated. By default the browser inspects the headers of the HTTP response generated by the web server. There are four headers commonly used for caching:

- ETag
- Cache-Control
- Expires
- Last-Modified

For more information about how it works please read https://medium.com/@codebyamir/a-web-developers-guide-to-browser-caching-cc41f3b73e7c